# How would water behave on a planet with no moons?

Tags: science-based, hard-science, moons, water-bodies

My novel is set on a planet covered in 90% water with no moons. How would the lack of natural satellites effect the waves and wind?

Comment: Silly question, how would the lack of orbitals make things act differently to earth. I need to describe them so knowing this would help me with my realism.

Comment: It is rather difficult to answer a "hard science" question when so few details are provided

Comment: Throw in that the planet is earth like, with a Sun like star, and rephrase the question itself to ask how the oceans are different from earths specifically because of no moon, and you have a solid question, which is probably a duplicate of another question somewhere here.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it will have small difference, mostly with [tidal forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force) reduced. They will still be there from the central sun, so the [Tide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tide) will still be in effect for your oceans. However it will have way lower amplitude.

The tide does generate waves globally, bit with less differences between high and low they will be generated in less manner by this thing. But they will still be generated standardly by the wind and heat processes (so heat exchanges between cold and warm seas by streams and similar).

The wind is not affected a lot by moon (but yes, there are tidal proccesses for athmosphere as well!), it is mostly affected by heat changes (so day/night cycle), by surface heat (on desert you will have more warm air than in forest), and by [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force), that is caused by the rotation of planet. The heat problem is that warmer air is lighter, so tends to raise up. This is the main part of the "wind generator", causing the [athmospheric circulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_circulation).

The moon has way bigger effect on sea tide than sun, as popularly known.However, for example [this article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/does-the-moon-have-a-tida/) mentions that the tide effect on higher athmospere is way bigger from the sun than from the moon, so the lack of the moon will have smaller impact on athmosphere tides than on sea tides.

Answer (score -1):

The *lack* of orbitals would have *no* effect on wind, water or anything. Because there's no orbitals to apply any effect to anything.<sup>1</sup>

<sub><sup>1</sup>Well, that was almost too easy</sub>

Comment: So not having orbitals is equivalent to having orbitals in regards to wind, water, and everything? we can get rid of our moon and have no consequences?

Comment: @Ryan that seems to be two questions. The latter has been extensively discussed on a multitude of questions on here, why not do a quick search?

Comment: You must enlighten me then as to why OP asked the question. I assumed we only know in depth about one planets water cycle and how the moon affects its oceans (Earth). Hence op was probably asking what an earth like planet in an earth like situation would be like with 90% water coverage and no moon, Or basically, what would happen to the oceans if they rose to 90% coverage, and we lost our moon.

Comment: @Ryan if that assumption were to be correct then my answer had to be revised. But as of now the only thing stated in the question is about how *no* Orbitals affect water and wind on a Spheroid with 90% water coverage; reducing this to the simplest possible thing we have *How does nothing affect something* to which the logical hard answer will always be: *Nothing has no effect on something*

Comment: -1 This is a cute answer, but does not answer the question. OP is looking for the differences between a planet with orbitals and a planet without, specifically with relation to the water and the wind. So, yeah, the lack of orbitals wouldn't have an effect on anything, but what does that mean/look like?